# Why isn't comment-reply.js moving my comment form?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a hand-built theme (WP v3.1.3 here), so I imagine it's a tag that I've omitted that's keeping the form from moving.

Some troubleshooting that I've already looked into:

- Script: loading fine, without errors in the console.
- Present: reply URLs referencing comment ID (`?replytocom=2#respond`)
- Present: `<ol class="commentlist">`
- Present: `<li id="li-comment-2" ...`
- Present: `<div id="respond">` encapsulating the comment form
- Reply link looks good: `onclick='return addComment.moveForm("comment-2", "2", "respond", "39")'`

The JS function in question:

```
addComment = {
    moveForm : function(commId, parentId, respondId, postId) {
        var t = this, div, comm = t.I(commId), respond = t.I(respondId), cancel = t.I('cancel-comment-reply-link'), parent = t.I('comment_parent'), post = t.I('comment_post_ID');

        if ( ! comm || ! respond || ! cancel || ! parent )
            return;

        t.respondId = respondId;
        postId = postId || false;

        if ( ! t.I('wp-temp-form-div') ) {
            div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = 'wp-temp-form-div';
            div.style.display = 'none';
            respond.parentNode.insertBefore(div, respond);
        }

        comm.parentNode.insertBefore(respond, comm.nextSibling);
        if ( post && postId )
            post.value = postId;
        parent.value = parentId;
        cancel.style.display = '';

        cancel.onclick = function() {
            var t = addComment, temp = t.I('wp-temp-form-div'), respond = t.I(t.respondId);

            if ( ! temp || ! respond )
                return;

            t.I('comment_parent').value = '0';
            temp.parentNode.insertBefore(respond, temp);
            temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
            this.style.display = 'none';
            this.onclick = null;
            return false;
        }

        try { t.I('comment').focus(); }
        catch(e) {}

        return false;
    },

    I : function(e) {
        return document.getElementById(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: without a link to either some HTML or a site we can look at: this is almost impossible to debug.

Comment: Sure, here's a snippet of the start of the output (not the raw PHP): http://pastie.org/2011982

Comment: @craig: what exactly is the desired functionality? What *should* happen when the comment reply link is clicked?

Comment: This WP (core) script relocates the comment reply form below the comment being replied to without a page refresh. It is the default behavior for current WP installs.

Comment: ...hold on... I think I've got a lead: the script is testing for 'cancel-comment-reply-link' and I believe isn't finding it. Standby.

Comment: @Craig: to be honest, I can't see anything obvious. Is there a live site that I can look at that has this issue?

Comment: @Craig: Yeah, that could be it.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts » That was it. Problem description updated with resolution. It was the comment form in the billiard room with the candlestick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script wasn't happy with the way my theme was concealing the link with `id="cancel-comment-reply-link"` -- as seen in the script: `cancel = this.I('cancel-comment-reply-link')` -- and was failing because of it.